# Footable Border not Showing

Tags: html, css, html-table, footable

Have some issues with the FooTable plugin and even thought its a long shot I thought I would ask for some help here.

[image: 1]

Regardless of what I try I cannot get the table to print thicker borders on the right side.

The only CSS I am trying to put in is as follows.

```
table.footable tbody{
border: 2px solid #000;
}


table.footable thead tr:not(.footable-filtering){
border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

And the HTML as follows.

```
<table id="<?php echo $tableid;?>" class="greyrow table no-border" data- 
paging="true" data-paging-size="50" data-filtering="true" data-filter- 
space="OR" data-filter-delay="20000">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date / Time</th>
            <th>UL ID</th>
            <th>Bench</th>
            <th>Source</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

```
if ($count >= 1) {

    print '<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        print '<td>'.($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : '').'</td>';
        }
    print '</tr>';
                        }

}

    print '</tbody></table><br>';]
```

Any help or advice would be really appreciated. I just cant make the one line thick! For some reason its not outputting all of the php tags but they are there.

Edit 1: In general it won't let me apply any borders to the right side of a FootTable table.

Comment: Is $count >= 1 ?

Comment: Yea count if always greater than 1 if the query pulls back any data.

Comment: But in your case is it greater or equal than 1? Put there an else and print something there. Is it printed?

Comment: No it doesn't print anything else in that situation, it is just there to print the headers on only the first pass through.